# Is it smarter to bet on a result with a lower probability but a higher reward?

Tags: probability

Imagine you were betting:

There is a result where your calculated probabilities for a win of team 1 is 40% and the quotas are 2.0. 
Your calculated probabilities for a win of team 2 is only 35% but the quatas are 3.0... for which team should u bet?

So basically, up to which point should you bet for the result with the higher probability and is there a way to calculate that point?

Comment: Depends on the ratio.  Just multiply the reward by the chance of winning to decide what is a better bet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected value is used to measure how good a bet is and the statistical outcome.
$$E_1 = 40/100 \times 2 = \frac{4}{5}$$
$$E_2 = 35/100 \times 3 = 1.05$$

Go with team $2$.

Comment: A follow up question... do you just add two different results to get the probability of several results together... e.g.: Quotas of 5.0 on getting exact result x (10%) and and quotas of 2.0 of the team winning (30%). So the complete result is 5.0×0.1 + 2×0.3?

Comment: You would add the positive results and minus the bad results.

Comment: This way you gain an overall expected value.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the expected value of each possibility by multiplying the payoff by the probability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

In your example:
Team 1 is 2.0 * 0.4 = 0.8
Team 2 is 3.0 * 0.35 = 1.05

Thus, Team 2 is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Soft answer: you usually want to go with whichever has the higher expectation, which as Roskiller has pointed out is team two. But this isn't always the  smartest choice. For example, would you rather pay \$1000 for a one-in-one million chance of winning 100 billion dollars (an expected gain of \$99,000), or pay 10$ for a 10% chance of winning \$1000 (an expected gain of \$90)? The second one is clearly a better deal, because you are almost guaranteed to lose the first bet, even though the expected gain is much higher.

I don't know a lot about the game theory here or anything, but often you should value certainty above raw expectation in real-life scenarios where you can't repeat the bet ad infinitum for the law of large numbers to kick in. However, in a case where the probabilities of winning are similar and neither is tiny, expectation definitely makes sense as the criterion to look at.

Comment: Not actually betting with real money but you get points for the correct results. Just thought it would be easier to explain with betting